# Troubles with af:inputFile component getFilename() method encoding

Tags: oracle-adf

I have realized file uploading into DB BLOB field as it was described in the Timo Hahn article:

http://tompeez.wordpress.com/tag/afinputfile

Code fragment:

```
// The event give access to an Uploade dFile which contains data about the file and its content

UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile) valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();

// Get the original file name

String fileName = file.getFilename();
```

Everything works fine, but I have some troubles with file name encoding. I try to get file name, using getFilename() method, but it works fine only with latin charset, however it fails for files with RUSSIAN charset in file name, e.g:

Original file name: my_file.doc -> my_file.doc

Original file name: заявки.png -> 70O2:8.png

Any ideas how could I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD 27.09.2012:**

I have found interesting bug. If I add ***file*** variable from code above into watches I will see **_encoding** property equals "**utf8**". If I change this property to "**null**" everything works fine!

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding you have set for your compiler and at the top of your JSF page.

Comment: I have already checked it. The encoding is UTF-8. P.S. <af:inputFile> is placed on page fragment.

Comment: To clarify this, you see the atring filename ni the wrong encoding, not the data in the db?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. The problem is in string filename encoding, not in data in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Open the project properties, select the compiler node and check the selectedd character encoding. It should be utf-8 in your case.

Comment: I have just checked these settings, - the value is UTF-8.

Comment: So what is the locale of the browser? if every other setting is utf-8 it should work. Have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: Browser locale - Russian. Browser cache has been cleared. I have just run your example - it works fine! I am trying now to compare settings in your example with our application... Very strange...